# Does apple app review team reject the app for the Xib or Storyboard design issues (warnings) in iOS?

Tags: ios, storyboard, warnings, appstore-approval, nib

I am having an app which is having some warnings. Does apple app review team reject the app for the warnings?

And mainly warning are generated from the XIBs and the Storyboard file.

Comment: Why don't you fix the warnings? They are important and must not be ignored.

Comment: @rmaddy, I can fix the warnings but from switching from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8 it is showing too much warning because of the new size classess and the deprecations of methods and classes.

Comment: Then it is even more important to fix them. A warning almost always represents a bug waiting to show up somewhere in your app. Do yourself and your customers a favor and fix them.

Comment: Ok. I will try to fix them as much as possible. Because my client wants this app as soon as possible.
Thanks @rmaddy

Comment: Your client also wants an app that works and will get good reviews.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never refused for this.
Only for functionality that aren't permitted

I suggest you to read this: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: No, Apple doesn't reject you for warnings.

If your app works and you are following all the guidelines, your app should be approved by Apple.